# Python/Raspbian - why does object SPI property (_spi_seq) change on Buster python 3.7.3 but not Jessie python 3.4.2 - probably spidev issue

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I recently started a job, where the requirements for coding were not made clear to me before I took it on. I'm enjoying it, but the learning curve has been massive as I've never used OOP before. This problem has me stumped so any help would be gratefully received - even if it just shows I'm missing the obvious!

I'm currently trying to update code on a Raspberry Pi 3B running an old version of Raspbian Jessie so that it will run on Buster. The code is over 10,000 lines long but this simplified snippet illustrates the problem that is the root cause of many problems when running on Buster. The code communicates with another chip on a pcb using SPI. The other chip is programmed with registers and CUSTAT is one of them. All registers exhibit the same problem. I'm confident it's not an SPI issue - communications have been checked and work.

The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import spidev, time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

DEV_OE   = 18   #GPIO24
SPI_MOSI = 19   #GPIO10
SPI_MISO = 21   #GPIO9
SPI_SCK  = 23   #GPIO11
SPI_CE0  = 24   #GPIO8
SPI_CE1  = 26   #GPIO7

PROFILER = 40   #GPIO21

PINS_OUT = [DEV_OE, PROFILER]

def rpi_init():
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(PINS_OUT, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(DEV_OE, 1)


def SPI_init():
    global spi
    spi = spidev.SpiDev(0,0)
    spi.max_speed_hz=(500000)

def SPI_xfer(bytelist):
    rxed = spi.xfer(bytelist)
    return rxed

class Reg8_Variable():
    def __init__(self, name, spi_seq):
        self._spi_seq = spi_seq
        self._value = "None"
        self.name = name

    def read_from_CPLD(self):
        #byteseq = [0x01, 0x00] 
        byteseq = self._spi_seq
        print ("byteseq", byteseq)
        rxed = SPI_xfer(byteseq)
        print ("SPI received ", rxed)
        self._value = rxed[1]

CUSTAT = Reg8_Variable("CUSTAT", [0x01, 0x00])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("start")
    rpi_init() #sets up GPIO pins
    SPI_init() #initialises SPI comms protocol
    for i in range(5):
        print (i, CUSTAT.name, CUSTAT._value, CUSTAT._spi_seq)
        CUSTAT.read_from_CPLD()
        print (i, CUSTAT.name, CUSTAT._value, CUSTAT._spi_seq)
        time.sleep(2)
```

When it runs on Buster using python 3.7.3 the value of CUSTAT._spi_seq is changed to the value of the read SPI when read_from_CPLD is run. Expected behaviour is that CUSTAT._spi_seq stays at [0x01, 0x00]. CUSTAT.value should either read 0x01 or 0x05 depending upon whether a switch on the pcb is pressed. Output is

```
start
0 CUSTAT None [1, 0]
byteseq [1, 0]
SPI received  [0, 5]
0 CUSTAT 5 [0, 5]
1 CUSTAT 5 [0, 5]
byteseq [0, 5]
SPI received  [0, 0]
1 CUSTAT 0 [0, 0]
2 CUSTAT 0 [0, 0]
byteseq [0, 0]
SPI received  [0, 0]
2 CUSTAT 0 [0, 0]
3 CUSTAT 0 [0, 0]
byteseq [0, 0]
SPI received  [0, 0]
3 CUSTAT 0 [0, 0]
4 CUSTAT 0 [0, 0]
byteseq [0, 0]
SPI received  [0, 0]
4 CUSTAT 0 [0, 0]
```

Commenting out byteseq = self._spi_seq and replacing it with byteseq = [0x01, 0x00] gives the correct output below:

```
start
0 CUSTAT None [1, 0]
byteseq [1, 0]
SPI received  [0, 5]
0 CUSTAT 5 [1, 0]
1 CUSTAT 5 [1, 0]
byteseq [1, 0]
SPI received  [0, 5]
1 CUSTAT 5 [1, 0]
2 CUSTAT 5 [1, 0]
byteseq [1, 0]
SPI received  [0, 1]
2 CUSTAT 1 [1, 0]
3 CUSTAT 1 [1, 0]
byteseq [1, 0]
SPI received  [0, 5]
3 CUSTAT 5 [1, 0]
4 CUSTAT 5 [1, 0]
byteseq [1, 0]
SPI received  [0, 5]
4 CUSTAT 5 [1, 0]
```

Running the original code (with byteseq = self._spi_seq) on Jessie with python 3.4.2 gives the correct output below:

```
start
0 CUSTAT None [1, 0]
byteseq [1, 0]
SPI received  [0, 5]
0 CUSTAT 5 [1, 0]
1 CUSTAT 5 [1, 0]
byteseq [1, 0]
SPI received  [0, 5]
1 CUSTAT 5 [1, 0]
2 CUSTAT 5 [1, 0]
byteseq [1, 0]
SPI received  [0, 5]
2 CUSTAT 5 [1, 0]
3 CUSTAT 5 [1, 0]
byteseq [1, 0]
SPI received  [0, 1]
3 CUSTAT 1 [1, 0]
4 CUSTAT 1 [1, 0]
byteseq [1, 0]
SPI received  [0, 5]
4 CUSTAT 5 [1, 0]
```

The hardware is the same - I only switched out the SD card on the Pi. What causes the difference in behaviour between python 3.4.2 and 3.7.3?

Sorry for the long question and thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:
So I have a workaround. Changing the code to:

```
def read_from_CPLD(self):
    byteseq = self._spi_seq.copy()
    print ("byteseq", byteseq)
    rxed = SPI_xfer(self._spi_seq)
    print ("SPI received ", rxed)
    self._value = rxed[1]
    self._spi_seq = byteseq.copy()
```

gives the expected response. However, I still don't understand what caused the _spi_seq list to be changed and why only in 3.7.3 and not 3.4.2.

Any explanations gratefully received.

Comment: A better fix is to do the list copy on the argument of the SPI_xfer() function. Clearly this is where it's being changed.

Comment: RX overwriting TX in spi.xfer reported as a bug here:

https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev/issues/119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause is bug in spidev - see my 2nd comment.